# RestKit Mix NSPersistentStore With Simple Request

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have configured a shared RKObjectManager and added mappings for many of the more complex objects in my project.  Now I have a need for a simple request and response, but want to use the configuration I have done to my shared object manager.  How do I go about making a request that isn't in the scope of my persistent object store (RKManagedObjectStore) but still use my shared object manager?

Answer (score 0):

The object manager uses the mappings to decide what to do with regards to saving objects to core data or plain objects (vinyl returned in the mapping result). Specifically this is controlled by use of `RKObjectMapping` and `RKEntityMapping'. As such you can't reuse the entity mappings outside core data but you can use the same object manager. Basically, set the appropriate path patterns on your response descriptors.